# Открытие вкладки при клике в любом месте

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как мне написать код на javascript, чтобы при нажатии на любую ссылку на странице параллельно открывалась вкладка с другим сайтом ( и это только раз в день - задействовать кукис). Мб есть готовое решение у кого уже?

```
onClick="window.open('http:// ') target ="_blank"
```

Comment: Подсказка: какой элемент DOM самый "верхний"? На него и вешать. Многие браузеры и баннерорезки этот трюк отключают.
P.s. очень надеюсь, что никогда не зайду на ваш сайт.

Comment: Это очень бесит? =) Просто хотелось бы по максимуму народ перебросить на сайт, который нужно развивать. Написал ссылку а никто не заходит...И да я пробывал вешать на body - получалось нужно кликнуть в пустоту, а мне нужно по ссылкам

Comment: @qwerty555 это не очень бесит, это **ОЧЕНЬ ОЧЕНЬ** бесит

Comment: ok ридерект всего и вся в htaccess ))))

Comment: @qwerty555 не забудьте указать 301 в редиректе, чтобы и поисковик это понял.